# how to return choices value in mongoengine stringfield

Tags: python, flask, mongoengine

Hi i'm using flask with mongoengine here is my model

```
class Change(db.Document):
    code = (('CAD', 'Dolar Canadiense'),
            ('GBP', 'Libra Esterlina'),
            ('MXN', 'Peso Mexicano'),
            ('CHF', 'Franco Suiso'),
            ('EUR', 'Euro'),
            ('DKK', 'Corona Danesa'),
            ('SEK', 'Corona Sueka'),
            ('JPY', 'Yen Japones'),
            ('CUP', 'Peso Cubano'),
            ('PAB', 'Balboa Panama'),
            ('AUD', 'Dolar Australiano'),
            ('USD', 'Dolar Estadounidense'),
            ('NOK', 'Corona Noruega'))

    fecha = db.DateTimeField(required = True, unique_with = 'moneda')
    moneda = db.StringField(max_length=3, choices=code, required = True)
    recanje = db.FloatField(required  = True)
    canje = db.FloatField(required = True)

    @db.queryset_manager
    def objects(doc_cls, queryset):
        return queryset.order_by('date')
```

How can i get the values of de choices when i make the query:

```
moneda = Exchange.objects.distinct("moneda")
```

return:

```
['Dolar Canadiense','Libra Esterlina'...]
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I would suggest that you replace your `code` variable with a dictionary like so:

```
codes = {'CAD': 'Dolar Canadiense',
         'GBP': 'Libra Esterlina',
         'MXN': 'Peso Mexicano',
         'CHF': 'Franco Suiso',
         'EUR': 'Euro',
         'DKK': 'Corona Danesa',
         'SEK': 'Corona Sueka',
         'JPY': 'Yen Japones',
         'CUP': 'Peso Cubano',
         'PAB': 'Balboa Panama',
         'AUD': 'Dolar Australiano',
         'USD': 'Dolar Estadounidense',
         'NOK': 'Corona Noruega'
         }
```

You can then change your model to only store the currency code:

```
codigo_moneda = db.StringField(max_length=3, choices=codes.keys(), required = True)
```

and add a property to return the currency's full name:

```
@property
def nombre_moneda(self):
  return self.codes[self.codigo_moneda]
```

Answer (score 4):

To get verbose name of choice item you need to call `obj.get_<field name>_display()`

So to get your list you need to do something like this:

```
[i.get_moneda_display() for i in moneda]
```